# How to create a dropdown list containing the categories in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a file to add a category, and a file to add a subcategory. In this file, I want to create a drop-down list that includes (categories in the database), I have created a database called "store" - contains: the category table for categories contains two fields, one for identifier and the other for the category name, and a table "subcat" for subcategories contains On 3 fields ... ID field, subcat_nm field for subcategory, parent_id field for class ID that is, >> cat_id = parent_id

```
`CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `cat_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_nm` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `subcat` (
  `subcat_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `subcat_nm` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subcat_id`)
);`
```

config.php

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
ob_start();
session_start();

define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'store');


define('PROJECT_NAME', 'test');
$dboptions = array(
              PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE, 
              PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
            );

try {
  $DB = new PDO(DB_DRIVER.':host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD , $dboptions);  
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
  die;
}

//get error/success messages
if ($_SESSION["errorType"] != "" && $_SESSION["errorMsg"] != "" ) {
    $ERROR_TYPE = $_SESSION["errorType"];
    $ERROR_MSG = $_SESSION["errorMsg"];
    $_SESSION["errorType"] = "";
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "";
}
?>
```

These are codes for adding a subcategory
The file addsubcategory.php

```
<? php
require_once './config.php';
?>
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "panel panel-primary">
      <div class = "panel-body">
        <form class = "form-horizontal" name = "contact_form" id = "contact_form" enctype = "multipart / form-data" method = "post" action = "process_subcategory.php">
          <input type = "hidden" name = "mode" value = "<? php echo ($ _GET [" m "] ==" update ")?" update_old ":" add_new ";?>">>
          <input type = "hidden" name = "subcat_id" value = "<? php echo intval ($ results [0] [" subcat_id "]);?>">
          <fieldset>
<div class = "form-group">
<label class = "col-lg-4 control-label" for = "subcat_nm"> Choose category </label>
              <div class = "col-lg-5">
<? php
        // Here I want to create a dropdown list containing the categories from the database
           ?>
              </div>
            </div>
<br> <p>
            <div class = "form-group">
              <label class = "col-lg-4 control-label" for = "subcat_nm"> Add subcategory </label>
              <div class = "col-lg-5">
                <input type = "text" value = "<? php echo $ results [0] [" subcat_nm "]?>" placeholder = "" id = "subcat_nm" class = "form-control" name = "subcat_nm" required = "required">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
              <div class = "col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-4">
                <button class = "btn btn-primary" type = "submit"> Submit </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

process_subcategory.php file

```
<? php
require './config.php';
$ mode = $ _REQUEST ["mode"];
if ($ mode == "add_new") {
  $ parent_id = trim ($ _ POST ['parent_id']);
  $ subcat_nm = trim ($ _ POST ['subcat_nm']);
  $ error = FALSE;
  if (! $ error) {
    $ sql = "INSERT INTO` subcat` (`parent_id`,` subcat_nm`) VALUES ". "(: parent_id,: subcat_nm)";
    try {
      $ stmt = $ DB-> prepare ($ sql);
      // bind the values
$ stmt-> bindValue (": parent_id", $ parent_id);
      $ stmt-> bindValue (": subcat_nm", $ subcat_nm);
      // execute Query
      $ stmt-> execute ();
      $ result = $ stmt-> rowCount ();
      if ($ result> 0) {
        $ _SESSION ["errorType"] = "success";
        $ _SESSION ["errorMsg"] = "Added successful.";
      } else {
        $ _SESSION ["errorType"] = "danger";
        $ _SESSION ["errorMsg"] = "The addition failed.";
      }
    } catch (Exception $ ex) {
      $ _SESSION ["errorType"] = "danger";
      $ _SESSION ["errorMsg"] = $ ex-> getMessage ();
    }  }
  header ("location: addsubcategory.php");
}
?>
```

Please Helppppp

Comment: Kindly post minimal code so that we can debug it easily. Like what is your error, expected output.

Comment: All that space-padding EVERYWHERE is unnecessary, unexpected, and is likely to lead to typo errors as well as other developers misunderstanding your code.  Please have a look at PSR standards and align your scripting practices with the rest of the world.

Comment: A field with `$ results [0] [" subcat_id "]` will not access value in the `subcat_id` column in the first row of the result set because of that whitespace padding.  You don't have a column with a leading whitepace called `[whitespace]subcat_nm` so the INSERT will fail and generate an error. Check your error logs. I'm voting to close as Typo.

Comment: This `: parent_id` will never work. Remove the space

Comment: Where do you try to create a dropdown list in your code?